# Command not working?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I don't understand what I need to do to fix this command.

I'm trying to make a firework star that has attributes and also a colour, and I'm just constantly getting the message *Encountered multiple top tags, only one expected* Help would really be appreciated!

```
/give @p firework_charge 1 0 {Explosion:{Type:4,Colors:[255]}},display:{Name:"green",Lore:["QDADSAD"]}
```

Answer (score 4):

You ended your first JSON statement with one too many braces, and forgot one on the end.

/give @p firework_charge 1 0 {Explosion:{Type:4,Colors:[255]}**}**,display:{Name:"green",Lore:["QDADSAD"]}**}**

Which leaves you with:

```
/give @p firework_charge 1 0 {Explosion:{Type:4,Colors:[255]},display:{Name:"green",Lore:["QDADSAD"]}}
```

Comment: Very small note: while it may look similar, this is the NBT format rather than JSON.